# Values not getting edited in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, javafx

```
int t1, t2 ,t3, asg, att;

    t1=Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
    t2=Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
    t3=Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText());
    asg=Integer.parseInt(tf4.getText());
    att=Integer.parseInt(tf5.getText());

    try {
       preparedStatement = connect
             .prepareStatement("update mark set test1="+t1+" && test2="+t2+" "
                     + "&& test3="+t3+" && asgmnt="+asg+" && attendance="+att+" "
                     + "where clsnum='"+cnum+"'");
       preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
```

With the above code I tried to edit 5 values in a table named 'mark'. But the values are getting edited. All the TextFields(tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5) were filled. TextField 'tf1' was filled with 24 by me. But after editing the table the values of 'test1' column is 0. No other column values are changed. How can I make the values edited ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect. Here's how you write the update query:

```
update mark set test1 = _value_, test2 = _value_,
test3 = _value_, asgmnt = _value_, attendance = _value_
where clsum = _value_
```